# Deleting the first string on the first line of two consecutive lines with identical stings at the beginning

Tags: text, vim, sed

I am working on text files (copied and pasted from a facebook group) I have stripped out all the strings "Like" "Comment" comment numbers etc with group of  sed commands  . I am left with  lines that look like this:

```
Jane Doe
Jane Doe Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec ac urna ut quam sagittis placerat id vitae justo. 
John Doe
John Doe Maecenas id justo tempus, auctor velit in, porta nibh. 
John Doe
John Doe Maecenas id justo tempus, auctor velit in, porta nibh. 
Fred Crun
Fred Crun Maecenas id justo tempus, auctor velit in, porta nibh. Mauris bibendum et ligula molestie faucibus. Nullam feugiat tristique sapien non fringilla. 
Fred Crun
Fred Crun Maecenas id justo tempus, auctor velit in, porta nibh. Mauris bibendum et ligula molestie faucibus. Nullam feugiat tristique sapien non fringilla.
Frank Zappa
Frank Zappa Suspendisse malesuada libero id tortor scelerisque feugiat. Suspendisse vel feugiat est. Vestibulum vel nisl magna. Aenean viverra diam vel vulputate pulvinar. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
```

I am looking for a regexp for `sed` or other Unix utility that would remove the name on the line(s) with no other text following, leaving the lines looking  like this:

```
Jane Doe Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
John Doe Maecenas id justo tempus, auctor velit in, porta nibh.
John Doe Maecenas id justo tempus, auctor velit in, porta nibh.
Fred Crun Maecenas id justo tempus, auctor velit in, porta nibh. Mauris bibendum et ligula molestie faucibus. Nullam feugiat tristique sapien non fringilla
Fred Crun Maecenas id justo tempus, auctor velit in, porta nibh. Mauris bibendum et ligula molestie faucibus. Nullam feugiat tristique sapien non fringilla.
Frank Zappa Suspendisse malesuada libero id tortor scelerisque feugiat. Suspendisse vel feugiat est. Vestibulum vel nisl magna. Aenean viverra diam vel vulputate pulvinar. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
```

ode here.

. I looked at `uniq` and several examples of regep in `gvim` but I could not see a way to achieve my aim . Names may consist of 3 words.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, but if you only print odd row number then you can use:

    **awk 'NR%2==1 {print $0}' $filename**

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to remove the  line containing the duplicate name but no other text . Please see my edit to the question for a more accurate version of the file working on .  thanks for your suggestion  I tried with the text above and it returned 
Jane Doe
John Doe

Comment: [edit] your question to show the output you expect given the input you provided, not some other output from some other input you haven't provided. Also clarify if names are **always** 2 words or can be multiple like `Arthur Conan Doyle`.

Comment: Done @Ed Morton

Comment: Then how can you tell what's a 3-word name from a 2-word name followed by 1 word of "extra text"? Why isn't `Donec ac urna ut quam sagittis placerat id vitae justo.` included in the output? If it was preceded by a line that was `Donec ac urna ut quam sagittis placerat id vitae` then [your accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889462/1745001) would print it - is that really your desired behavior?

Comment: The first incidence of the name is never followed by anything else . If the second incidence of name is followed by anything then I wish to keep it. The issue I have is the duplication of the name on a line followed by empty space above the line with the name and any following information. The supplied answer did exactly what I wanted, deleted the line including the name only leaving the second line and any subsequent text.   Please help me understand where you think how I might have asked the question better for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;/^(.*)\n\1./!P;D' file
```

Open a two line window throughout the length of the file.

If the whole of the first line is the same as the start of the second, do not print it.

Delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: I never knew that back references were available to be used as part of the regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Vim you can do the following:

```
:%s/^\(.*\)\n\1/\1
```

Which looks for a line, followed by `\n` and the same line (plus potentially something after, it is not specified) and replaces it with the pattern found, removing the first part.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in `d` file, tried on gnu sed:

```
sed -E '/^\w+\s\w+\s*$/{N;s/([^\n]+)\n(\1.+)/\2/;b};d' d
```